# How Does BlazeDS Generate Files

Tags: flash, blazeds

I've been giving a application to work on that uses a Java EE application for the backend, Flash for the front end, and BlazeDS to connect the two. I have never used Flash or BlazeDS, and am trying to get my head around how BlazeDS works.

So far, I understand that when you connect to BlazeDS in FlashBuilder, the `remoting-config.xml` file is scanned to determine what services exist on the Java end. FlashBuilder asks which of these services you want to import, and what "service package" and "data type package" you want to use.

When you select your Java `ExampleService`, BlazeDS will  create `_Super_ExampleService.as` and `ExampleService.as` and put them in your "service package" location. `ExampleService.as` is empty but extends `_Super_ExampleService.as` (which basically is a Flash service that you can use to call the methods in your Java service). If you need to add extra methods, you would add them to `ExampleService.as`. (Hopefully this is all correct, please correct me if I'm wrong)

My problem is I cannot figure out what BlazeDS does for value objects.

When you select `ExampleService` in FlashBuilder (let's assume it's a service for the `Example` entity), what value objects does BlazeDS create? I would expect `Example.as` and `_SuperExample.as`. However, `_ExampleEntityMetadata.as` also appears.

My questions are basically:

1. How does BlazeDS determine what value objects to create? Does it scan the DB, scan the project for @Entity annotations, scan some config file, scan the service to determine what objects it works with, etc?
2. What purpose does each of the 3 classes serve? It looks like the same setup with the service (change the non-"_Super" one if needed), but there is now that 3rd file.
3. I noticed the value objects do not always correspond directly to the Java entities (has additional properties, missing properties, etc). Why is this?
4. How are the value objects used in conjunction with the services?

I also had some general questions:

1. When you connect to a service in FlashBuilder, what are you actually doing? The first time, I imagine BlazeDS makes the necessary services and value objects. But what if they're already there (say you already connected, or you pulled down code and connected for the first time)? Does connecting just make the services available in your copy of FlashBuilder?
2. Is it guaranteed that BlazeDS will always generate the services and value objects the same way? Like line for line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just buying a [Kindle book on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004ASOR0M) and reading through some of the chapters (specifically, chapter 26). Here is basically what I learned:

- Over the course of time, Adobe products evolved and separated until "LifeCycle Data Services" (LCDS) was established. This technology sits on the server and provides various features.
- Adobe released "BlazeDS" as a free version of LCDS (with fewer features).
- The feature that I am using of BlazeDS is the "Remoting Service" (there is also the "Message Service" and "Proxy Service"). The remoting service allows you to call Java service methods from your Flash front end. Data is passed between Flash and Java via a binary format called "Action Message Format" (AMF).
- **SUMMARY** BlazeDS sits on the server and allows Flash and Java to communicate via AMF.

In order to be able to call the Java methods in Flash, do the following (note: I assumed default naming):

- Create a normal Java POJO (some restrictions: need a default constructor, methods must be public to be available, etc).
- In `remoting-config.xml`, add a destination for the service. You'll notice there is a channel called `my-amf`. If you look in `services-config.xml`, you'll see the corresponding channel definition and that it uses AMF and points to your running application (using dynamic expressions).
- When configuring the Flash Builder project, you provide the location of your web application so it knows where it's suppose to send requests to.
- **SUMMARY** You allow Java communications by creating your Java service, configuring it in `remoting-config.xml`, and letting your Flash project know your webapp location (so it can know where to find the Java objects).

At this point, you can call your services manually in MXML or ActionScript, like below (assume we have an `ExampleService` in Java mapped as `exampleService` in `remoting-config.xml`).

```
//MXML
<s:RemoteObject id="myExampleService" destination="exampleService" />
<s:Button label="Call a Method" click="myExampleService.myMethod()" />

//ActionScript
var myExampleService:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject("exampleService");
myExampelService.myMethod();
```

*Note: There is much more to learn about the above (and similar things), like handling results, etc. But I won't get into that.

Now, to connect to pass data between Flash and Java, it becomes serialized. The conversion from Flash types to Java types is not perfect. For example, a Flash `Array` turns into a Java `List`/`Map`. And a Java `List`/`Map` turns into a Flash `ArrayCollection`/`Object`. Because of this, you can use a "value object" design pattern. Basically, you create a Flash object that mirrors a Java object that your services deal with. So if you had an `Example` Java class, you would create maybe a `ExampleVO` Flash class. You'd need to annotate the Flash class with `[RemoveClass(alias="my.package.Example")]`, etc.

To make life easier however, you can automatically generate these files. BlazeDS communicates with Flash Builder via "Remote Development Service" (RDS) protocol. In your `web.xml` file, you can enable a `RDSDispatchServlet`. Once RDS is enabled, you can make data connections in Flash Builder (Data > Connect to BlazeDS).

And, as an answer to the question, the book states:

`By default, if a Java class's public method returns an instance of a strongly 
typed value object class, the connection wizard creates a matching ActionScript
value object class. The conversion of the server-side data to ActionScript value
object happens at runtime and is managed by the generated code.`

Comment: The beginning of this video talks about generating the services and value objects: http://tv.adobe.com/watch/flex-in-a-week-day-2/generating-value-objects-using-flash-builder-data-services/

Answer (score 3):

There are few confusions here. What Blaze does is as follows:

1. Implements AMF format (this is the native Flash format for serializing Flash objects). So that it knows how to write and read Flash objects.
2. Implements some extended functionality required for Flex framework (which is actually a bad thing because it's poorly written and you never need it, but that's a whole separate story). For example it provides series of classes to mimic their Flex analogues in Java and on the Flex side it mimics maps, trees and so on (never even try to use that).
3. Creates a special handler(s) that will be loaded by your web server (Tomcat, JBoss etc) and handle the incoming connection from Flash. This handler is instantiated per session - whatever that means in your context. This handler is also known as FlexHandler (this is how it usually appears in the configuration files).

What Blaze doesn't do:

1. It doesn't generate source files (no value object sources are generated - you must do it on your own). However it has some commonly used types - all numeric types, strings, booleans, some collections etc.
2. It doesn't reflect on the existing code and doesn't integrate into Flash Builder. The program that does it is called Fiber, it is provided by Adobe (same source), but it is entirely different thing, it is a proprietary product, it pursues other goals (it can generate code for languages other then Java for example).

Fiber is mostly an experimental product, it was introduced in Flash Builder 4 (that is about a year ago), and it is currently extremely raw. Basically it is only useful as an illustration, or a proof of concept, but it hasn't been tested in the field (and it's hard to find volunteers :)

remoting-config.xml is not a special name of any kind, however, by the virtue of an example that many a lot copied from, the name is recognizable as a part of services-config.xml (the name, again, has no special meaning and can be changed, however, it's commonly referred to by this name). These files have dual purpose. When Flex application is compiled, these files can be used by Flex compiler in order to create some default setups for RemoteObject (you probably don't want to do it that way, unless you are really confident about what you are doing, but even then, you wouldn't probably want to do it that way...). On the other hand, these settings are used by the FlexHandler (mentioned above) in order to know where should it expect Flash client to connect. The later is a particularly difficult subject because it's impossible to debug Blaze code in a sane way, and it's very difficult to discover what exactly the base URL is etc. Luckily for you, you can replace this abracadabra: `<endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf"` with something more conscious like `<endpoint url="http://server-name/gateway"` (i.e. no need to search for the values of `server.name` and `server.port` - it is really very difficult to find where they are hiding.

The classes generated by Fiber (EntityMetadata, _SuperXxx and so on) are, by the long run, harmful. It is an attempt to reflect on Java code and to instill some similar logic into AS3 code. Alas, people who wrote that had no clue as to how AS3 works - so what happens there is pure madness.

There are certain rules in how you translate Java value object into Flash:

1. On any one side you can add more properties that don't exist on the other side. Blaze won't populate them (obviously), but the properties will exist and will be available. The drawback is - you'll get a bunch of rutnime errors (suppressed) on both sides. In order to avoid this, on AS3 side you can mark an unwanted property as `[Transient]`. But, think twice before you do that - this is a sign of bad design. Ideally, you shouldn't need this. I don't know what the Java analogue of Transient is.
2. You cannot have a property with the same name, but different type - this kind of errors is not suppressed.
3. Traditionally for Java properties of Boolean type are named `isSomething` - for Blaze you'll have to make an exception, or name them `(get|set)IsSomething` if you insist...

Value objects are created by Blaze on the side of Java, when it invokes the Java functions that are meant to be the service handlers. They, obviously, appear as arguments to the handlers. Value objects are created on Flash side by Flash player itself - this creates certain problems, such as - no way to pass enumerators - it will attempt to call constructor on AS3 class anyway. No non-default constructor arguments are allowed.

When you connect to service in Flash Builder - please don't do it. No one actually knows what exactly you are doing. The code is proprietary and no promise about feature freeze etc has been made. As of today, it is much easier for someone who can program, by means other then mouse clicking, to actually write the program code, rather then do it in a step-by-step wizard way.

Blaze only generates value objects at run time - you can be almost certain about that. It is predictable and if there will come a major change, you will be surely notified :) Blaze does not generate source code.

Comment: How is it that Fiber and BlazeDS interwork? This questioning was basically started from our process (which I can't change): 1) Bring down the code from the repository (Subversion in our case), 2) Run the Ant scripts to compile etc, and 3) Connect to BlazeDS. On step 3, Subversion recognized the service and value object files were changed. I am trying to figure out why they changed.

Comment: FYI, a lot of my (maybe misguided) info came from http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/category/flex-and-blazeds/ which seems to suggest BlazeDS makes the services. So maybe Fiber is intertwined somehow and the author didn't state that.

Comment: Yes, like the link I mentioned talks about, our `web.xml` sets up a `RDSDispatchServlet`.

Comment: And I am not sure if it's the compiling that does the updates. The reason I thought BlazeDS was responsible was because the services and valueObjects remain the same (i.e. matches Subversion) until you do a Data > Connect To BlazeDS in FlashBuilder. Then they change (without calling Ant scripts or anything).

Comment: My company is extremely unique. Lol. I am suppose to be cleaning up this crappy project. And I'm trying to get to a point where everyone can bring down the code, setup, connect to BlazeDS and have 0 things that say they needed checked into Subversion at that point. But those damn value objects keep changing.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your help. I ended up buying a book and actually reading some ;) It looks like it was the `RDSDispatchServlet` (as you mentioned) and that value objects are created to help serialization. I selected my outline as the answer so that future people would get a quick idea of what's going on. Sorry I didn't choose yours. I am not sure that Fiber is what's causing things, but the Blaze/FlashBuilder communications and `RDSDispatchServlet`. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem on the FlashBuilder. Our company is pretty strict on what we use. Thanks for the info :)